# find number of files & total size of files modified in last 30 days in Linux

Tags: linux, ls

I have a huge file vault (File directory) in Linux where files are added/modified daily, I want to find number of files & total size of files modified in last 30 days in Linux. How can I do it?

Comment: Before giving you an answer I would 1/ recommend posting that not on SO but on super user and 2/ you should try by yourself something based on date (to get date - 30 days), pipes, ls -l and awk (to grep the date and check it against date-30 and adding the size). Should not be too hard but at least give it a try

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [`find`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find) command can find the files that have been modified (mtime) or created (ctime) within a certain amount of time. [`wc`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/wc) can tell you the number of bytes in a group of files. [`xargs`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xargs) converts words in the standard input into arguments to a command.

```
find /path/to/vault -mtime 29 -type f | xargs wc -c
```

`find` is probably one of the most useful tools for helping to identify files that have properties of interest to you. I guarantee that taking the time to learn it will be time well spent.